# AWS::S3::Errors::InvalidAccessKeyId

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So, I'm running rake db:drop db:create db:migrate db:seed and for some reason I'm getting the following error:

```
AWS::S3::Errors::InvalidAccessKeyId: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
```

Bare in mind, most of the migrations run however, I seem to be getting the error directly after this migration:

```
 20140606122523 CreateActiveAdminComments: migrated (0.8930s) ===============
```

I have all of the updated keys in the appropriate files as follows:

**config/aws.yml:**

```
defaults: &defaults
  access_key_id: '*key here*'
  secret_access_key: '*key here*'
  bucket_name: '*bucket name*'

development:
  <<: *defaults

test:
  <<: *defaults

production:
  <<: *defaults
```

**initializers/aws.rb**

```
AWS.config(YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join("config/aws.yml"))[Rails.env])
```

What am I doing wrong? I've double and triple checked the keys, and have even tried generating new ones.. Still getting the same error.

Please help!

Comment: Can you post the contents of that migration? Why would you be receiving this error with `S3` - this doesn't hold databases, right?

Comment: Correct.. the migrations contents are standard.. that's why this is so strange.

Comment: It's not referencing Paperclip or any other dependency requiring `s3` is it?

Comment: Actually you're quite right.. it is. It has the line: "add_attachment :sliders, :image"

Comment: Ahhh. Have you tried un-setting your `Paperclip` `S3` settings? So the migration will work - then we can work on the getting S3 connectivity sorted?

Comment: That solved it - at least temporarily! It was the paperclip s3 settings, it was having trouble pulling the ENV variables from the application.yml file. So i've inputted them directly for now. If you want, put that as an answer and I'll accept. Thanks!!

Comment: Better yet, is there a way we can find out .. why it's not pulling the ENV variables correctly?

Comment: I'll write the answer- which V of Rails are you using? This could be solved in 4.1.0 with the introduction of [`secrets.yml`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html)

Comment: Ok great, I'm using Rails 4.

Comment: Updated answer for you sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Migration**

After a discussion in the comments, the issue was that the migration referenced `Paperclip`, which used `S3` settings. To fix the migration, the OP had to remove the `Paperclip` S3 settings from the `config/application.rb`, allowing the migration to proceed.

--

**ENV Vars**

The `ENV` vars are slightly different

It's strange how you'd try and set them in the `application.rb` - by their nature, [environment (ENV) variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) are meant to reside in the OS - making them accessible by your app & other parts of the system. It's just another security feature to help keep data both secure & modular

The problem you have is setting ENV vars in development is about putting the variables on the machine, and it's also the case that Rake won't load them *unless* they are available at OS-level

The solution you need is two-fold:

--

[**secrets.yml**](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html#config/secrets.yml)

Rails 4.1.0 introduced **secrets.yml** to help fix this:

> Rails 4.1 generates a new secrets.yml file in the config folder. By
>   default, this file contains the application's secret_key_base, but it
>   could also be used to store other secrets such as access keys for
>   external APIs.

```
#config/secrets.yml
If you upgrade to Rails 4.1, you'll get a `secrets.yml` file which will look like this:
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

# Your secret key is used for verifying the integrity of signed cookies.
# If you change this key, all old signed cookies will become invalid!

# Make sure the secret is at least 30 characters and all random,
# no regular words or you'll be exposed to dictionary attacks.
# You can use `rake secret` to generate a secure secret key.

# Make sure the secrets in this file are kept private
# if you're sharing your code publicly.

development:
  secret_key_base: [a salt]

# Do not keep production secrets in the repository,
# instead read values from the environment.
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

You'll be able to put your API keys in there, and then reference using `Rails.application.secrets.some_api_key`

--

**figaro**

An alternative, which is just as effective, is to use the [figaro gem](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro). This is kind of redundant with `secrets.yml` but anyway, it creates an `application.yml` which you can then reference using the direct `ENV["setting"]` var

Either way should solve your issue!